# Getting Correct Child in Firebase Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following JS code.

```
  var database = firebase.database();
  database.ref().child('server/user-search').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      var content = '';
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        var val = child.val();
        content += '<tr>';
        content += '<td>' + val.deviceCodename + '</td>';
        content += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#ex-table').append(content);
    }
  });
```

[image]

This is the layout I have. Its the child within user-search. Thanks for the help

Comment: What are you trying to do? What have you tried? What isn't working in this code?

Comment: What am I trying to? Create an admin panel so I can view the stats. What have I tried? See above! What isnt working? Im guessing my child is wrong....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra node "0" between the "user-search" UID and the deviceXXX nodes.

If I make the assumption that this extra node is always "0", you should do something like the following:

```
    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref().child('server/user-search').once('value', function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
                var val = child.val()['0'];
                content += '<tr>';
                content += '<td>' + val.deviceCodename + '</td>';
                content += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#ex-table').append(content);
        }
    });
```

Comment: yeah i noticed that extra node... its weird that android is adding that in... ill have to look at my code.

Comment: What is the type of your object when you save it to the database?

Comment: -> A list. I think if I change it to a Map<String,Object> it would eliminate the added 0?